# Dlang,Socket,Chat Server

Tags: multithreading, sockets, oop, chat, d

I want to write a chat server. 
Using the programming language D. (Dlang)
It is desirable to use OOP.

My example.(Not working)

```
import std.stdio;
import std.concurrency;
import core.thread;
import std.conv;
import std.socket;

synchronized class DataInfo{
    shared this()
    {
    }
    public shared Socket[] sockList; 
    shared void AddSocket(shared Socket scket)
    {
        sockList ~= scket; 
    }

    shared(Socket[]) getSockList()
    {
        return to!(shared Socket[])(sockList);
    }
}
void UserLoop(shared DataInfo data,shared(int) id)
{
    Socket client;
    synchronized(data)
    {
        client = cast(Socket)(data.sockList[id]);
    }

    while(true)
    {
        char[1024] buffer; 
        int sockCount = 0;
        client.receive(buffer);
        synchronized(data)
        {
            sockCount = data.sockList.length;
        }

        for(int i =0 ; i < sockCount; i++)
        {
            synchronized(data)
            {
                auto sk = cast( Socket)(data.sockList[i]);
                sk.send("Hello world");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

        ushort port;
        port = 4444;

        auto listener = new TcpSocket();
        assert(listener.isAlive);
        listener.blocking = false;
        listener.bind(new InternetAddress(port));
        listener.listen(10);
        writefln("Listening on port %d.", port);
        shared(DataInfo) data = new shared(DataInfo);
        while(true)
        {
            int len = 0;
            auto client = cast(shared Socket)listener.accept();
            synchronized(data)
            {
                data.AddSocket(client);
                len = data.sockList.length; 
            }
            spawn(&UserLoop,data,cast(shared int)len);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

How? How to fix the bug?
Can I get an example of correct chat servers? (Only Dlang)
Also, can you give an example of the correct client.

Comment: Why are you using threads? They are so much more complicated and so often not worth it compared to simpler solutions like just using select(), or even epoll and friends if you need more concurrent sockets (though select does a good enough job for a great many programs). But anyway, this program would be like half the length without threads and less buggy too.

Comment: You might take a look at this old project of mine, which of course could use some optimization, but right now I do not have anything else. https://github.com/BaussProjects/dasocks and used it for a simple webserver here https://github.com/BaussProjects/daweb or perhaps even this would be of help https://github.com/BaussProjects/ProjectXV4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import vibe.d;
import vibe.utils.array;

shared static this()
{
    Chat m_chat=new Chat();
    ushort port=5555;
    listenTCP(port,&m_chat.connHandler,"127.0.0.1");
}
class Chat{
private:
        TCPConnection[] connz;
public:
    void connHandler(TCPConnection conn){
        sendMessage(conn,"Hello!\n");
        connz~=conn;
        while(conn.connected){
            while(conn.waitForData(dur!"seconds"(1L))){
                ubyte[1] c;
                string inMessage;
                while(conn.dataAvailableForRead){
                    conn.read(c);
                    inMessage~=c;
                }
                foreach(TCPConnection _con; connz){
                    if(_con!=conn)
                        sendMessage(_con,"Someone says: "~inMessage);
                }
            }   
        }
        connz.removeFromArray(conn);
    }
    void sendMessage(TCPConnection conn, string message){
        conn.write(cast(ubyte[])message);
    }
}
```

Solution suggested by Lord_Evil